# Error whilst trying to use client.latency in a cog

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to use a ping command with my bot, and the code for it is in a cog. I have an idea about what's wrong but I have no idea how to fix it as I am new. Whenever i use the 'f.ping' command I get the following error:

```
Ignoring exception in command ping:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\josep\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 903, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\josep\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 847, in invoke
    await self.prepare(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\josep\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 784, in prepare
    await self._parse_arguments(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\josep\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 690, in _parse_arguments
    transformed = await self.transform(ctx, param)
  File "C:\Users\josep\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 535, in transform
    raise MissingRequiredArgument(param)
discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument: client is a required argument that is missing.
```

This is my code for ping.py:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

class Ping(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    @commands.command()
    async def ping(self, ctx):
        await ctx.send(f'Pong!' ({round(client.latency * 1000)}ms))

def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(Ping(client))
```

I have narrowed the problem/error down to the `({round(client.latency * 1000)}ms` part, but I have no idea how to fix it. The command works perfectly fine with that part removed. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have 2 different errors, let's help you get back on track.

First off, you have an error with your f-string. The quotes are incorrect, so you need to place them in the correct spots.

```
await ctx.send(f'Pong! ({round(client.latency * 1000)}ms)')
```

Now, your other error is because you're coding in a class, you used *client.latency* instead of *self.client.latency*. So, this would be the correct code:

```
await ctx.send(f'Pong! ({round(client.latency * 1000)}ms)')
```

import discord
from discord.ext import commands

```
class Ping(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    @commands.command()
    async def ping(self, ctx):
        await ctx.send(f'Pong! ({round(self.client.latency * 1000)}ms'))

def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(Ping(client))
```

If you want to read about *self* and *f-strings*, here are some useful links:
[Self](https://www.programiz.com/article/python-self-why)
[F-strings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/)

Answer (score 1):

You got two errors.

**Frist**: f string quotes are incorrect:

Wrong:

```
await ctx.send(f'Pong!' ({round(client.latency * 1000)}ms))
```

Right:

```
await ctx.send(f'Pong! ({round(client.latency * 1000)}ms)')
```

**Second**: Since this is a cog you should use self.client.latency, keep in mind the **init** function, you assigned *self.client = client*

Wrong:

```
await ctx.send(f'Pong! ({round(client.latency * 1000)}ms)')
```

Right:

```
await ctx.send(f'Pong! ({round(self.client.latency * 1000)}ms)')
```